# Finding integral $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(mt) \cos(\lambda t) dt$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am a little stuck on the following problem:

Prove that:

$$\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(mt) \cos(\lambda t) dt = -2 \frac{(-1)^{m} \lambda \sin(\pi \lambda)}{m^2 - \lambda ^2}$$

I have used the fact that:

$$\cos(mt + \lambda t) + \cos(mt - \lambda t) = 2 \cos(mt) \cos(\lambda t)$$

to set up:

$$\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(mt) \cos(\lambda t) dt = \frac{1}{2} \left[\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(m + \lambda)t dt + \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(m - \lambda)t dt \right ]$$

Solving the integrals on the right, I have managed to obtain:

$$\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(mt) \cos(\lambda t) dt = \frac{(m- \lambda)\sin((m + \lambda) \pi) + (m + \lambda) \sin((m- \lambda) \pi)}{m^2 - \lambda ^2}$$

However, I don't see where I go from here to get the final expression $$-2 \frac{(-1)^{m} \lambda \sin(\pi \lambda)}{m^2 - \lambda ^2}.$$

If anyone can help me out here, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Note that the integrand is an even function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identities for $\sin(a+b)$:
$$(m+\lambda)\left(\sin(m\pi)\cos(\lambda\pi) + \cos(m\pi)\sin(\lambda\pi)\right)+$$
$$(m-\lambda)\left(\sin(m\pi)\cos(\lambda\pi) - \cos(m\pi)\sin(\lambda\pi)\right)=$$
$$(-1)^m \sin(\lambda\pi)\cdot(m-\lambda-m-\lambda)= -2(-1)^m\lambda\sin(\lambda\pi)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!  Didn't think about using the identity again.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

We start with $$\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \cos(mt) \cos(\lambda t) dt = \frac{(m- \lambda)\sin((m + \lambda) \pi) + (m + \lambda) \sin((m- \lambda) \pi)}{m^2 - \lambda ^2}$$

Here, $m$ is an integer, and $\sin((m + x)\pi)=(-1)^m \sin(x\pi)$. This let's you expand the numerator into exactly the form that you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Greatly appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that $m$ is an integer so that $\cos{m\pi} = (-1)^m$.  Expand the sin terms in the numerator and verify your result.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Yeah, I get the correct answer now :)